# Sfsync04 file is corrupted

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers

I don't know exactly what I did, but somehow the sfsync04.sys (drivers) file is corrupt, and now I can't start my windows. That's the error startup repair gives me, and it is unable to correct it automatically. I'm currently running a live version of Ubuntu, so I can access my files, and everything seems to be alright except for the sfsync04.sys file.

Is there a way I can repair that file so I can avoid reinstalling Windows for now?

I'm running windows 7 64 bits. The file is in windows\system32\drivers\ . I think this happened when I tried to install some legacy software, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you boot into safe mode?

Try to boot into safe mode and delete the sfsynco4.sys file in the system 32 folder.

Try to boot now.

Uninstall that software if it boots ok.

Otherwise follow this link and boot from an Ubuntu CD and delete the file.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/

.